# Plotting thousands of observations on a single graph

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to plot `Date` on the X axis and `Revenue` on the Y axis. I have data for about 16000 customers, revenue aggregated on a weekly basis. The data set looks like the example dataset below (except that I have data for about 100 weeks and 16000 customers):

```
CustNum    Date    Revenue
1    2013-01-07    35
1    2013-01-14    23
1    2013-01-21    42
1    2013-01-28    65
2    2013-01-07    78
2    2013-01-14    48
2    2013-01-21    85
2    2013-01-28    34
```

I would like to plot this data on a single plot with one line on the plot representing one customer. In other words, the plot will have more than 16000 lines on it showing `Revenue` for each customer, each week.

Now, I understand that this plot will be really messy with 16000 lines on it, I would like to have suggestions on what could be a better way to plot this data so it is not as cluttered.

I tried the following code which didn't give me the desired result:

```
p <- ggplot() + geom_line(data=res,aes(x=Date,y=Revenue,color=custnum))
```

This didn't give me multiple lines for multiple customers.

So I basically have two questions:

1. What could be a better way to represent this data?
2. How can we improve my code to show 16000 lines on a single plot? (I don't care about this question a lot if I can get another way to represent this data)

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Comment: What information are you trying to convey with your plot? That there is a general tendency among customers? Or on the other hand that there is great variability? Decide _what_ you want to show, and only then choose _how_ to show it.

Comment: After I plot this information I will be trying to show that certain Marketing campaigns affected a subset of total customers, which I will subset and show on the same plot. So eventually, the effect of Marketing campaigns will be displayed.

Comment: maybe `geom_line(data=res,aes(x=Date,y=Revenue,group=CustNum),alpha=0.2)` ?

Comment: @Patthebug What I mean is, do you want to show trends over time, a point after which things changed, that sort of "_what_". I'm just trying to understand if you really need lines. Boxplots or violin plots could be an option, for instance... Anyway, you'll find it hard to come up with 10 easily discernible colours, let alone 16000. Those lines will be indistinguishable, and thus, useless, IMHO.

Comment: @ZéLoff - I agree that the colors will not be distinguishable at all. To your question, yes I would like to show that things changed after a particular point for some customers, whereas for others, things were consistent. Eg. We ran a campaign aimed at a few customers, the question is how did the campaign affect the revenue associated with those customers. I guess I should specifically be looking at the affected customers, not all customers at the same time.

Comment: A couple of suggestions based on the comments. First, to show what you are trying to show, consider normalizing each customer to the first week's value. Then you ought to aggregate by the campaign variable for visualization. Another option is to simply color by campaign, perhaps using transparency.

Comment: Following on vpikt's point, you could add a factor variable, say 'treatment' that takes two values based on your customer: 'campaign' and 'no campaign' and that distinguishes between those customers subjected to the campaign and the rest. Then you plot your data as boxplots to showcase the level of variance in the data associated with each group of customers and differentiate between them using your 'treatment' variable as fill argument. Or you could choose to facet your plot using 'treatment'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R outline of the approach in my comment above.  I use a large matrix to hold all the data. The first column is whether the customer got the treatment. The subsequent columns are the weekly revenue for 100 weeks.

First, I will simulate some data, this has a lot of temporal noise.

```
#First records are a stable pattern
notreat<- matrix(c(rep(0,8000), 100+rnorm(8000*100,0,5)),nrow=8000)
#second set of records get no treatment for 50 weeks    
treat<- matrix(c(rep(1,8000), 100+rnorm(8000*50,0,5)),nrow=8000)
#then get the treatment for 50 weeks
treat<-cbind(treat, 
             matrix(rnorm(50*8000,100+0.75*(0:50)),nrow=8000,ncol=50,byrow=TRUE))

m <- rbind(notreat, treat)

#use a color palette with transparency to be able to discern the overall pattern.
palette ( c(rgb(.4,0,0,0.01),rgb(0,0,0.4,0.01)))


#This will take several seconds to render 16000 lines
matplot(t(m[,2:101]),col=1+m[,1],type="l")
```

You can get your data frame into the type of matrix I build here using something like `unstack()` or the `reshape` package.

Comment: I am yet to apply this to my data and reshape it in the desired format, but this looks pretty much like what I wanted. I ran your code and the output was a beauty, much like a watercolor painting. Thanks a lot for your help mate.

Comment: I drew inspiration from Nathan Yau of flowingdata.com. He has lots of nice R examples

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking at something like this:

```
CustNum = c("1","1","1","1",
            "2","2","2","2")
Date = c("2013-01-07","2013-01-14","2013-01-21","2013-01-28",
         "2013-01-07","2013-01-14","2013-01-21","2013-01-28")
Revenue = c("35","23","42","65","78","48","85","34")

df = as.data.frame(cbind(CustNum,Date,Revenue))

df$CustNum = as.factor(df$CustNum)
df$Revenue = as.numeric(as.character(df$Revenue))

## create the factor variable
df$Treatment = ifelse(df$CustNum == '1','campaign','no campaign')

ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=Date, y=Revenue, color=Treatment), size=5) + facet_wrap(~Treatment)
```

Results: [image: Plot]

Now you can imagine doing the same with switching `geom_point` with `geom_boxplot` or `geom_errorbar` across all your data points. You could alternatively opt for not faceting and just plot in one graph, but you'd have to specify within the geom call the option 'dodge' to avoid having you boxplot stacked over one another.

Results2: [image: Plot2]